# Laravel images doesnt show up on live server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I cant access my images when I run on my live server but it work on local. I have doubled check and my url is right but the images still doesnt show up

mysite.com/public/vendor/Beautymail/assets/images/sunny/logo.png

```
%PUBLIC%/vendor/Beautymail/assets/images/sunny/logo.png
```

I only get a: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

*I am using Laravel Forge with DO

Comment: It's strange to have a **vendor** folder inside public. **vendor** folder (for composer) should be in the root folder.

Comment: remove the `/public` part: mysite.com/vendor/Beautymail/assets/images/sunny/logo.png

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it because Windows isn't case sensitivity but Linux is.

Try to change all the directories and files names to lowercase letters and also in your url, so that your new url will be: (notice that all letters are lowercase):

```
mysite.com/vendor/beautymail/assets/images/sunny/logo.png
```